# Implementing a multilingual WordPress site by installing several instances of WordPress and redirecting

Tags: php, redirect, wp-redirect, multi-language

I am developing a website with WordPress which is going to support 4 languages. My primary language will be English and there will be 3  other languages.

For this reason, I have installed WordPress on public_html folder of my host and then created **three other folders named fr, it and ar for French, Italian and Arabic** respectively inside the public_html. Then I installed another instance of WordPress on each sub-directory. My goal was to have different admin panels for each language.

Finally, I tried redirecting based on IP of the visitor to a relevant website every time my website gets visited by a user. To implement this I used the following code:

```
function redirect_based_on_ip($country_code) {
echo($country_code);
$url = get_site_url();
if($country_code == "FR"){
    wp_redirect($url."/fr");
    exit;
}else if($country_code == "IT"){
    wp_redirect($url."/it");
    exit;
}else if($country_code == "DZ" || $country_code == "BH" || $country_code == "EG" || $country_code == "IQ" || $country_code == "JO" || $country_code == "KW" || $country_code == "LB" || $country_code == "LY" || $country_code == "OM" || $country_code == "QA" || $country_code == "SA" || $country_code == "SD" || $country_code == "SY" || $country_code == "AE" || $country_code == "YE"){
    wp_redirect($url."/ar");
    exit;
}else{
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
}
```

}

Please note that the $country_code parameter is the output of another function that gives me the country code of the visitor based on his/her IP which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600004/3929525).

Unfortunately, I get the following error when I use this:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/myHostUsername/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:290) in /home/myHostUsername/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1296

As I used this code inside my functions.php file of the primary website (EN), I found that by adding the following line to functions.php the error disappears but this time, the redirecting does not work correctly and the code always gets inside the **else block which means English**.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_based_on_ip' );
```

I tested another way in which I installed every website in a single sub-directory (even primary one was installed inside public_html/en), and used an index.php file inside my public_html folder to do the redirecting and this way, everything was OK. But I don't want my primary version to be inside /en folder. How can I fix this?

By the way, please do not suggest me to use plugins as I don't want them.

Comment: You might not want to use plugins, but what you want to achieve is complex and already resolved pretty well via plugins - the main issues you will have are code redundancy ( 4 WP * installs, 4 * plugins, 4 * bugs, etc.. ) - I would suggest to look into reliable plugins like polylang, which will allow you local language admin and to connect post translations, as well as translate strings in your plugins and themes.. WP is - more or less - Multilanguage ready - no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @QStudio I cannot use plugins as the design of my website for different language will be different. Some languages are right-to-left plus I want to show slightly different content for each website.

Comment: You can use plugins for all of those things - "plugins" as a concept can be and do anything.. so perhaps you need to take the time to look at a few, test them and see how they work - at the very least as a reference point for taking on a complex task like mapping multiple WordPress installs together.

Comment: @QStudio I just tried polylang plugin, but there is an issue. Does it remember the user's choice or every time the user needs to select the language?

Comment: @QStudio What if I want to use different fonts for different language? These are all challenges of using a plugin.

Comment: It either takes from the browser locale, which does not require user action, or you can show a language dropdown / choice option - you can also translate some content and not others when connecting translated posts - and, yes, it remembers the user choice over page loads.

Comment: The alternative method might be WP multisite network, which shares one WP install, plugins and themes etc - but also allows you to have different features on each site.